# How to create a Laravel Eloquent Model from Collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, model

In order to use Algolia search with Airtable data, in a Laravel application, I think need to create an Eloquent model with the data I have retrieved, to then make use of Laravel Scout.

Can I use Collection data, that I have retrieved from Airtable, as a Model without a DB?

Answer (score 1):

there is a `hydrate` method for this:

```
YourModel::hydrate($collections->toArray())
```

But if you have only one object, you can just

```
$res = new YourModel($your_object)
```

Or you can even use `fill`

```
(new YourModel())->fill($your_obj)
```

And obviously until you don't call like `save` or `update` or something like this, where laravel tries to save that model on the DB, you're safe (maybe consider "disabling" them from the model, so that if you accidentally call those methods, nothing happens)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - and this Model would interact with Laravel Scout OK?

Comment: @MikeThrussell I would say yes, at least if you extend `Model` from laravel I don't see why there should be problem

Comment: Throws a MySql error: php artisan scout:import "App\Models\AirtableThing"


   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from `airtable_things` order by `id` asc limit 500)

Comment: @MikeThrussell well you said you don't have a database, and  `scout:import` for the does does: `If you are installing Scout into an existing project, you may already have database records you need to import into your indexes`... so either you have a database, or you don't want to use import...